# Why does main () display well "Lukaku" and contains_names() returns null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I've created an hashmap that normally can be use in method "main()" and "contains_names()", I add some element in the hashmap in the main's method but if I try to display them in "contains_names" it returns 'null', I don't understand why...

example :
if I try do System.out.println(names.get("Lukaku")) in "main" it will return 0

if I do the same thing into "contains_names()" it will return null

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class devideV2 {

    static int no_element=8;

    public static HashMap<String,Integer> names =  newHashMap<String,Integer>();


    /**
     *
     * @param arrays is an arraylist of String which contains some names (ArrayList)
     * @return the names who figure out more than an half or "null" if there's not (String)
     */
    public static String contains_names(ArrayList<String> arrays){

        //will return null but why ?
        System.out.println(names.get("lukaku"));

        //increment the value of the key that is represented by the first element of arrays
        names.put(arrays.get(0),names.get(arrays.get(0)+1));

        //will return True
        System.out.println(names.containsKey("Lukaku"));

        //At line 20 I've a null pointer Exception who has been thrown

        //if the name figure out more than an half then return this name
        if(names.get(arrays.get(0)) > (no_element/2)){
            return arrays.get(0);
        }


        //remove the name
        arrays.remove(0);

        //making recursion
        if(arrays.size()>0) {
            return contains_names(arrays);
        }

        //if no names figure out more than an half then return "null"
        return "null";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] names_array={"Lukaku", "Lukaku", "Lukaku", "Hazard","Hazard","Hazard","Hazard","Hazard"};
        ArrayList<String> Names_arrayList= new ArrayList<String>();

        //put every names in the Hashmap and their occurences to 0
        for(int i=0;i<names_array.length;i++){
            Names_arrayList.add(names_array[i]);
            names.put(names_array[i],0);
        }

        //will return 0
        System.out.println(names.get("Lukaku"));

        System.out.println(contains_names(Names_arrayList));
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you modify your names HashMap in the contains_names method? And what exactly is the purpose of `names.put(arrays.get(0),names.get(arrays.get(0)+1));`? I wouldn't expect that method to do any modification of the Map. If I am completely honest i can't even really figure out what that method is supposed to do and why you decided a recursive approach would be the right choice for that

Comment: shouldn't it be `names.put(arrays.get(0), names.get(arrays.get(0)) + 1 );` (parenthesis moved) - so it counts the names? shouldn't the method be called `countNames`? And it is probably returning `null` since no name sums to more than 8 (but code is easy to misunderstand)

Comment: As a general readability comment, avoid vague names like myarray and myarrayB - use descriptive names that describe the purpose of these variables, this makes the code easier for others to read and understand. Also, take a look for Java Coding Standards and apply common standards to your code, capitalization of Classes, camel-casing variable names etc, these also make your code easier to read.

Comment: I up to date my code (add some comments etc....) Sorry for the confusion. just a bit tired hihi

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

You got a typo in the brackets:

```
    names.put(arrays.get(0),names.get(arrays.get(0)+1));
```

This is were overwriting "Lukaku" with the count of "Lukaku1", which doesn't exist, so it returns null.

What you wanted is (with some proper formatting):

```
    names.put(arrays.get(0), names.get(arrays.get(0)) + 1);
```